# why is this sass command giving me an error

Tags: ruby, bash, sass, command

I am trying to learn sass so I can develop my front end skills a little bit more because that is what I hope to be some day. The only thing is I can't get sass to work.

Whenever I run the sass --watch . command it returns this error.

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      write ./test.css
LoadError: no such file to load -- rb-fsevent
      Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I did a bit of research on this error and it was suggested on this site to just simply install the rb-fsevent file that is missing so I ran the gem install rb-fsevent command and then got this error.

```
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.9.4.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

so I did a bit of research on THIS error and it was suggested agin on this site to just run the install with sudo. So i did just that I didn't get an error so i was quite excited because I have been fighting with this for a while so i want back to the start of this question and ran the --watch command and got the same exact error. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first error is because Ruby can't load the `rb-fsevent` gem. This could be because the gem is not installed. Trying to install the gem was a good idea.
2. Your second error is because you are trying to install the gem to a directory that you do not have permissions for. Using sudo to do the install is an acceptable solution. You can also do `gem install --user-install` to install to your home directory.
3. You are still getting the first error because even though the gem is installed, Ruby cannot load it. This could be because `sudo` installed the gem with the wrong permissions, or installed it to the wrong location, or Ruby is looking for it in the wrong location.

Thus your solution would be to

1. Locate the gem files you installed
2. Check that their permissions allow you to read them
3. Check `ruby -e 'p $LOAD_PATH'` to see if Ruby is looking in the right place for the gem

Comment: I have been looking around in the console for a while and I cant find the gem. I'm pretty new to the console and I have no idea what I am looking for, could you point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try `find / -name '*fsevent*'`